# Animating an SVG

Tags: processing

I'm using the program Processing to create an animation. One of the clips I'm struggling with is to make an object (In this case an SVG) move up to a certain point and then back down. The motion I was going for was a smooth, fast jab up and then slower going down and repeat this motion. I've managed to get this so far:

```
PShape gunhand;
float y = 600;
float speed = 3;    

void setup() {
  size(1280,720);
  gunhand = loadShape("gunhand.svg"); 
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  move();
  display();
}

void move() {
  if (y > 300) {
    y = y - speed;
  }
    else{y = 300;
  }
}

void display() {
  shape(gunhand, width/6, y, 1000,500);
}
```

Any help, I am greatful for, thanks!

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Heya, thanks for the reply! Sorry, my question is how can I make it go back down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be like this:

```
void move() {
  y = y - speed;
  if (y < 300) {
    speed = speed *-0.5;
    y = 301;
  }
}
```